# JAXB Marshaller with specified schema

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I want define schema in each xml file that I marshalling. And then get this schema (path string) at unmarshalling process. `marshaller.setSchema()` only

> allows the caller to validate the marshalled XML as it's marshalled.

Yes, I can write extra bean for this purpose, but I want get xml like

```
<root
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation='bla-bla.xsd'>...
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To specify a noNamespaceSchemaLocation you can do the following:

```
JAXBContext jc = JAXBContext.newInstance(Root.class);
Marshaller marshaller = jc.createMarshaller();
marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "bla-bla.xsd");
```

Comment: I have some problem with unmarshaling this property. Please, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4478666/unmarshaller-and-schema-in-jaxb

Comment: @Stas Kurilin, I have now posted an answer to that question that leverages a XMLStreamReader (StAX parser) to get the noNamespaceSchemaLocation.  Once the noNamespaceSchemaLocation is obtained JAXB can use the XMLStreamReader to perform the unmarshal.

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan while setting the property noNamespaceSchemaLocation I am getting javax.xml.bind.PropertyException: name: Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION value : "somexsd.xsd"

What could be the possible reasons for this error?

Comment: Can you do the same thing to get the version number of the schema? ie: <xs:schema... version="3.3"/> Thank you

Comment: bla-bla.xsd is, means, does, what?  non-existent file?