# Unmarshaller and schema in JAXB

Tags: java, xsd, jaxb

I have application that can save file in various formats (all of them is xml). So I should solve problem with determination in what format file have been saved. So, I see 2 solutions

- different formats have different schemas, so I could determine it by them.
  I set schemas in way that I get from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4473430/jaxb-marshaller-with-specified-schema)

`marshaller.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, "bla-bla.xsd");`

so I suppose I can get it using `unmarshaller.getProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION)`

but it throwing

> javax.xml.bind.PropertyException:
>   jaxb.noNamespaceSchemaLocation

and `getSchema()`  return null
So, **how can I get schema location?**

- Specifying different adapters for different beans using  `setAdapter(Class<A> type, A adapter)` method

What way is preferable? If first, then how can I get schema location label?

upd **code example**
suppose we have bean

```
@XmlRootElement
public class Foo{
    String bar;
    public String getBar() {return bar; }
    public void setBar(String bar) {this.bar = bar;}
}
```

and code that generates schema, saves Foo's instances and loads then.

```
public class Test {
    final static String schemaLoc = "fooschema.xsd";


    public static void write(File file, Foo foo, Schema schema) throws Throwable {
        XMLEventWriter xsw = null;
        try{
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
            XMLOutputFactory xof = XMLOutputFactory.newInstance();
            OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
            xsw = xof.createXMLEventWriter(out);
            Marshaller m = context.createMarshaller();
            m.setSchema(schema);    //schema setted
            System.out.println(">>>marchal : " + m.getSchema());    //check it
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.TRUE);
            m.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION, schemaLoc);
            m.marshal(foo, xsw);
        } finally{
             xsw.close();
        }
    }

    public static Foo load(File file) throws Throwable {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
        Unmarshaller unmarshaller = context.createUnmarshaller();


        System.out.println("unmarshaller schema:" + unmarshaller.getSchema());  //I need get it here
    //  System.out.println("schema_prop:" + unmarshaller.getProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_NO_NAMESPACE_SCHEMA_LOCATION));

        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file));
        XMLEventReader xer = XMLInputFactory.newInstance()
                .createXMLEventReader(in);
        return Foo.class.cast(unmarshaller.unmarshal(xer));
    }

    private static File createSchema(String schemaLocation) throws Throwable{
        final File target = new File(schemaLocation);
        if(!target.exists()){
            JAXBContext jaxbContext = JAXBContext.newInstance(Foo.class);
            SchemaOutputResolver sor = new SchemaOutputResolver() {
                public Result createOutput(String namespaceURI, String suggestedFileName)
                throws IOException {
                    StreamResult result = new StreamResult(target);
                    result.setSystemId(target.toURI().toURL().toString());
                    return result;
                }
            };
            jaxbContext.generateSchema(sor);
        }
        return target;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {
        createSchema(schemaLoc);
        File file = new File("temp.xml");
        Foo foo = new Foo();
        foo.setBar("test bar");
        SchemaFactory factory = SchemaFactory.newInstance(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_NS_URI);
        Schema schema = factory.newSchema(createSchema(schemaLoc));
        write(file, foo, schema);
        System.out.println("result " + load(file).getBar());
    }

}
```

schema that generates

```
      <xs:element name="foo" type="foo"/>

      <xs:complexType name="foo">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element name="bar" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:complexType>
    </xs:schema>
```

our temp file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<foo xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="fooschema.xsd">
<bar>test bar</bar></foo>
```

as we see, there is

> xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="fooschema.xsd"

How I can get this text using JAXB?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would leverage a StAX parser to get this information (see example below).  Create an XMLStreamReader on the input.  Advance the XMLStreamReader to the root element using the *nextTag()* method.  Then grab the noNamespaceSchemaLocation attribute of the root element.  Then pass the XMLStreamReader to the *unmarshal(XMLStreamReader)* method on Unmarshaller.

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import javax.xml.XMLConstants;
import javax.xml.bind.JAXBContext;
import javax.xml.bind.Unmarshaller;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLInputFactory;
import javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamReader;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Categories.class);

        XMLInputFactory xif = XMLInputFactory.newInstance();
        FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("input.xml");
        XMLStreamReader xsr = xif.createXMLStreamReader(fis);
        xsr.nextTag();
        String noNamespaceSchemaLocation = xsr.getAttributeValue(XMLConstants.W3C_XML_SCHEMA_INSTANCE_NS_URI, "noNamespaceSchemaLocation");
        System.out.println(noNamespaceSchemaLocation);

        Unmarshaller um = context.createUnmarshaller();
        Categories response = (Categories) um.unmarshal(xsr);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You have to provide it with the location of your schema by using a file our fileoutputstream reference:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html

EDIT:

Sorry, after reading further, you actually want the location of the schema, not the XML file, and there are quite a few examples online. Most of them like this one:

http://robaustin.wikidot.com/how-to-improve-perforamance-of-jaxb

Show how to pass in the schema location using a context class loader.

EDIT:

Per your comments:

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/bind/Marshaller.html#getSchema%28%29

getSchema() will return null if there is no schema set on the marshaller. That is why you can't get the property you want because it (the schema) doesn't exist.

Comment: Thanks, but it is desktop application, so it can be run at comp without internet / app can be moved and so on. So when I do marshalling I can only specify schema label. At unmarshalling I can generate schema using label. For this I need get schema's label.

Comment: My English isn't perfect( I'll try again. I know how get Schema from file. I do not know how get text that had wrote in `xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation=` attribute using unmarshaller.

Comment: +1, because after docs it should help, but it doesn't. I add some long code example for clarify.